# Save value from Action Sheet

Tags: cocoa, core-data, osx-mountain-lion

I am stuck on something dumb. This app is an OSX core-data app. I'm calling an action sheet to play with dates. The date selected is correctly shown on the screen after the sheet is closed. However, I cannot figure how to save the date.

Any help appreciated. This is the code I'm working with in my AppDelegate.m:

```
NSDate *theDate = [self.purchaseDatePicker dateValue];
    if (theDate)
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        NSString *formattedDateString;

        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

        formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];

        [self.purchaseDate setStringValue: formattedDateString];
        self.item.purchaseDate = theDate;
        [self.item setPurchaseDate:theDate];
        [self.item setPurchaseDate:self.item.purchaseDate];

        NSLog(@"theDate is %@", theDate); <-- this is fine.
        NSLog(@"item.purchaseDate is %@", self.item.purchaseDate); <-- this returns NULL

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = _coreDataController.mainThreadContext;
        if (![moc save:&error])
        {
            [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        }
            }
}
```

Comment: "*OS/2*" or "*Mac OS X*"..?  ;-)

Comment: It looks a lot like `self.item` is `nil`, can you check on that?

Comment: Tom you are right on. I'm now trying something like this: [itemArrayController setValue:theDate forKey:self.item.purchaseDate]; but I have to get my types straight. Other ideas really welcome.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte: Wait, is `self.item.purchaseDate` a date, a string representing a date, or a key identifying a property? You do not want to use that as the second argument to `setValue:forKey:` if it is not a key.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the follow-up - fwiw, I did not receive a notification that there was a comment (don't think so anyway).. self.item.purchaseDate is an attribute in a core data graph. As Tom H. noted, self.item is nil, and I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @Peter, I forgot to say, the attribute is an NSDate.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte: Then you should definitely not try to use it as a key. Only strings can be valid keys. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/

Comment: ok. thanks. Is it reasonable then to convert the date to a string and use that as the key? I will listen to the documentation (struggling with recent sight loss). Finally, how do I close this question?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte: That doesn't make any sense. You use KVC to set properties of an object; the array controller doesn't have a property whose name is a date, in any format. If you intend to store a date somewhere in the model objects that the array controller is holding, either use `setValue:forKeyPath:`, or get the specific object whose date-holding property you want to set and use `setValue:forKey:`; either way, you'll need to use a key path or single key (respectively) that identifies where in the model you want the date put.

Comment: As for closing the question, post an answer with your solution, then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers here very helpful, but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926015/synching-core-data-with-two-xib-simultaneously) really got me thinking. So today, the code looks like below, and it works great!!

1.

```
[itemArrayController setValue: [DatePicker1 dateValue] forKeyPath: @"selection.date1"];
```

2.

```
  if ([itemArrayController valueForKeyPath: @"selection.date1"] == NULL) {
        date1 = [NSDate date];
        [datePicker1 setDateValue: date1];
    } else {
        [datePicker1 setDateValue: [itemArrayController valueForKeyPath: @"selection.date1"]];
        date1 = [itemArrayController valueForKeyPath: @"selection.date1"];
    }
```